# Scroll page at top section

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have integrated scrollify in my wordpress website. there are six section. I have disabled update hash function. I have scrolled upto 4th section. then i reload the page. Page loads at 4th section directly. It should be load at top of the section.

How can i scrolled at top of the section each and every time.

Answer (score 0):

This is standard browser behaviour, when you scroll and reload the page, the browser will return you to your previous position. To force the browser to the top of the page would provide the user with a poor experience.